# MySQL differences between integer and varchar

Tags: mysql

I am really curious about difference between VARCHAR and INTEGER types.

For example, i want to store user's age. But how ? Is this important, it's integer, tinyint or varchar ?

Also for user's gender can be 0 for female and 1 for male.

I store age and gender as a 'tinyint', is this good approaching ?

Comment: `Integer` is for numbers, and `varchar` is for numbers, letters and other characters (Short text). So for age you can use a `int` type, for genders you can use the `enum()` type if there are only two options.

Comment: Varchar is text and integer is number. Is the user's age text or a number?

Comment: Have you read the [MySQL documentation page about Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html)?. The answers to your questions are there.

Comment: @JJJ i am not ask, is age number or a text. I can store it both type and i didnt see any perfomance difference between them. And i didnt think that reason is simple like your say.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is basically "I have a number. Should I store it as text or a number?" The answer *is* pretty simple.

Comment: @JJJ What is the point of being number or text? All are binaries and machine does not know their types... So i just wanted to and asked performance differences ok ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of things to clarify here...

- `VARCHAR` is to store text.
- `INTEGER` is to store integer numbers, as opposite to non-integers (numbers with a decimal point and a mantissa)

The datatype you choose should match the type of value you store in the field.
There are multiple reasons to this. The main reasons are storage space and ability to make computations on numbers.

An age is obviously always a number so you should you use an `INTEGER` to store it.

There are also multiple kinds of number and text fields, characterized by the space they occupate in the memory or the disk drive. It's important to choose the right type to store the right thing, especially when you have a lot of data. With 100 records in your table, it's not that important. With 1 billion records it is absolutely essential. But a good programmer/designer always keep that in mind and always think out-of-the box in terms of performance and costs.

For integers, you can choose amongst:

```
DataType    Range 
TINYINT     -128 to 127 
SMALLINT    -32768 to 32767 
MEDIUMINT   -8388608 to 8388607 
INT         -2147483648 to 2147483647 
BIGINT      -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
```

If you are storing a human age, chances are high that you will never go above 127 years old, so a `TINYINT` is acceptable, but just to be sure, take a `SMALLINT`.

On a side note, when possible it's always better to store a birthdate, so you can compute precisely the age at anytime. If you store the age only, then it will only be valid during one year, it won't be "dynamic".

For your GENDER, you have basically 2 approaches:

- Store it as `CHAR(1)` (one character) having values 'M' and 'F' for instance.
- Store it as a `TINYINT` like you did , it will act as a boolean (true or false - 1 or 0) and you have to define if male is true and female false, or the opposite, and apply the same scheme everywhere in your application.

You should really study [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) if you want to design your database properly.